# settings to change jqplot metergauge plot size

Tags: jquery-plugins, jqplot

I am trying to place jqplot meter gauge in the column of a table, I am able to place it but the size is bigger than the other columns.
Is it possible to make it smaller so that it fits properly into the table.

JsFiddle link for the same is //jsfiddle.net/sajesh1985/bu1p1guL/

Let me know how to fix this.

Thanks,
Sajesh Nambiar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution to this problem there is an attribute gridpadding in jqplot which we need to specify to align the plot properly in the table